# Decimal numbers with 16 digits after the point show strange behavior

Tags: pine-script

I have a question about decimal numbers with 16 digits after the point like [Babydogecoin](https://www.tradingview.com/chart?symbol=BABYDOGEUSDT) price. When I want to check this condition for MACD, the pine script does not show anything.

```
// Calculate MACD Data
fast_ma = ema(close, 12)
slow_ma = ema(close, 26)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = ema(macd, 9)
hist = macd - signal

// Check the condition
if hist < 0
     label.new(bar_index , high , tostring(hist))
```

The pine script does not understand that -0.000000000001 is a negative number!
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to the floating point precision limit. Due to the tiny base value of BABYDOGE you are most likely getting calculation results that are smaller than can be represented or calculated.